# How do I get missing parts for a Cobi set?

Tags: clone-brands, replacement-parts

I got the 1305 set from [Cobi](https://cobi.eu). I am missing 3 or more pieces. I can't complete the model without these pieces:

- 2 normal black 1 cm high, 6 studs long, rectangular (not round edge)
- 1 black rectangular flat 3 studs long, 2 studs wide.

How do I order only these parts?

Answer (score 3):

You can order individual parts using [Blocks by Piece](https://cobi.pl/en/blocks-by-piece).

I think the two parts you describe are [2x6 czarny](https://cobi.pl/en/blocks-by-piece/general-spare-parts/2x6-czarny,art,12505.html) and [2x3 1/3](https://cobi.pl/en/blocks-by-piece/general-spare-parts/2x3-13-,art,12903.html).

[image: 2x6 image]
[image: 2x3 image]